# Spring MVC Servlet with WebClient and OAuth Client Credentials

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am using WebClient in Spring MVC servlet based application (non-reactive) for accessing resources over HTTP from other microservices. Few of the resources are protected by client_credentials OAuth2 flow. It is very convenient to configure RestTemplate with OAuth2 Client Credentials, but now I am stuck configuring the same with WebClient. I can always get the Bearer token manually and then set it in WebCLient `setBearerAuth()` method, but that requires a lot of manual plumbing. My question is - does WebClient support Exchange Filter for automatic Client Credentials flow when used in Spring MVC application?

**UPDATE:**
I have found `ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction` that should solve client credentials auth flow. I am using the below code:

```
@Bean
WebClient webClient(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations, OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClients) {
    ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2 =
            new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrations, authorizedClients);
    oauth2.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("cart67");
    oauth2.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
    final WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .apply(oauth2.oauth2Configuration())
            .build();
    return webClient;
}
```

But the issue now is that this WebClient can not make calls to remote resource server when called from a scheduled job. I get the below error:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: 
           java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: request cannot be null
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: request cannot be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198)
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
```

Things work fine if i use this WebClient from a MVC controller instead of scheduled job. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might come from the `HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository` which is used to store the `OAuth2AuthorizationRequest` in a `HttpSession`. As your application works fine for incoming HTTP requests handled by your controller, this makes sense.

You might want to configure your `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` differently and don't store the information in the `HttpSession`.

The [Spring Security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2client) provides a good start here to pick and configure the correct one.